# Using WHERE and BETWEEN

Tags: mysql

I get correct response from this.

```
SELECT *, studentid, COUNT(studentid),be_user_profiles.first_name, 
be_user_profiles.last_name            
FROM be_user_profiles
LEFT JOIN hw_homework
ON be_user_profiles.user_id= hw_homework.studentid
WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
GROUP BY be_user_profiles.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(studentid) DESC
```

I want sort out between certain dates. But if I add BETWEEN, it gives an error.

```
SELECT *, studentid, COUNT(studentid),be_user_profiles.first_name,
be_user_profiles.last_name
FROM be_user_profiles
LEFT JOIN hw_homework
ON be_user_profiles.user_id= hw_homework.studentid
WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
AND WHERE hw_homework.date  >= $from AND  <= $to // neither AND WHERE hw_homework.date BETWEEN $from AND $to
GROUP BY be_user_profiles.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(studentid) DESC";
```

My table structure is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hw_homework` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `studentid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `subjectid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `assignment_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `teacherid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_completed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `entered_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=977 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hw_homework`
--

INSERT INTO `hw_homework` (`id`, `studentid`, `subjectid`, `assignment_name`, `teacherid`, `date`, `date_completed`, `approved`, `entered_by`) VALUES
(2, 128, 4, 'Asdf', 59, '2012-11-08 00:00:00', NULL, 1, 0),
(3, 96, 12, 'In Class Essay Practise', 67, '2012-11-09 00:00:00', NULL, 1, 0),
(4, 96, 11, 'Creating Want ', 64, '2012-11-09 00:00:00', NULL, 1, 0),
(5, 119, 13, '6A, Q1, 6B, Q1~Q3', 20, '2012-11-12 00:00:00', NULL, 1, 0),
...
...
```

Error message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2013-06-14 
00:00:00 GROUP BY be_user_profiles.user_id ' at line 6

SELECT *, studentid, COUNT(studentid),be_user_profiles.first_name, 
be_user_profiles.last_name FROM be_user_profiles LEFT JOIN hw_homework ON 
be_user_profiles.user_id= hw_homework.studentid WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = 20 
AND hw_homework.date BETWEEN 2012-08-23 00:00:00 AND 2013-06-14 00:00:00 GROUP BY
be_user_profiles.user_id ORDER BY COUNT(studentid) DESC
```

I appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong how to do it.

Comment: "it gives an error." And it doesn't occur to you to add that error here? It might help...

Comment: I don't get why I am getting -1 here?

Comment: Either for the same reason I posted a comment (never mentioned the error), or for the face that the error shows you are using a different query then you say you are using -> please post the exact query (and not add some comment halfway) that produces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere are several things wrong with your query, maybe you should take a look at the manual?

```
WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
AND WHERE hw_homework.date  >= $from AND  <= $to // neither AND WHERE hw_homework.date BETWEEN $from AND $to
```

1. you need only 1 where:

   ```
    WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
    AND hw_homework.date  >= $from AND  <= $to // neither AND WHERE hw_homework.date BETWEEN $from AND $to
   ```
2. I'm not sure what the comment is about:

   ```
   WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
   AND hw_homework.date  >= $from AND  <= $to
   ```
3. You should add `'` around dates:

   ```
   WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
   AND hw_homework.date  >= '$from' AND  <= '$to'
   ```
4. and finally, you need to add the column to the `<=`

   ```
   WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
   AND hw_homework.date  >= '$from' AND  hw_homework.date <= '$to'
   ```

That last query should work.

After your last edit: the problem with the actual query you seem to run is point 4: you don't have `'` around the dates

Comment: Thanks. #4 should be WHERE be_user_profiles.advisor = $id
AND hw_homework.date  >= '$from' AND  hw_homework.date <= '$to'